# Nested form validation statements repeating multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, callback

Given the following associations:

```
class Parent
  has_many :a_childs
  validates_associated :a_childs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :a_childs

  has_many :b_childs
  validates_associated :b_childs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :b_childs

  has_many :charges
  validates_associated :charges
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :charges

  validate :test_puts

  def test_puts
    puts "validating Parent - #{self.attribute}"
  end
end


class AChild
  belongs_to :parent

  has_many :charges
  validates_associated :charges
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :charges

  validate :test_puts

  def test_puts
    puts "validating AChild - #{self.attribute}"
  end
end

class BChild
  belongs_to :parent

  has_many :charges
  validates_associated :charges
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :charges

  validate :test_puts

  def test_puts
    puts "validating BChild - #{self.attribute}"
  end
end


class Charge
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :a_child
  belongs_to :b_child

  validate :test_puts

  def test_puts
    puts "validating Charge - #{self.attribute}"
  end
end
```

When I run a create like the below: a `Parent` with 2 `AChilds` each with 2 `Charges` and 1 `BChild` with 1 `Charge` and then finally with 1 `Charge` on the Parent itself, like the below:

```
Parent.create(
{
  "attribute" => "order",
  "a_childs_attributes"=> 
    [
      {
        "attribute"=>"a child 1",
        "charges_attributes" => 
          [
            {"attribute" => "a child 1 chg a"},
            {"attribute" => "a child 1 chg b"}
          ]
      },
      {
        "attribute"=>"a child 2",
        "charges_attributes" => 
          [
            {"attribute" => "a child 2 chg 1"},
            {"attribute" => "a child 2 chg 2"}
          ]
      }
    ]
  "b_childs_attributes"=> 
    [
      {
        "attribute"=>"b child",
        "charges_attributes" => 
          [
            {"attribute" => "b child chg"}
          ]
      },
    ]
  "charges_attributes" =>
    [
      {"attribute" => "order chg"}
    ]
}
```

I would expect the puts statements to run like the below:

```
validating Charge - a child 1 chg a
validating Charge - a child 1 chg b
validating AChild - a child 1
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 1
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 2
validating AChild - a child 2
validating Charge - b child chg
validating BChild - b child
validating Charge - order chg
validating Order - order
```

But instead what I'm getting is this:

```
# In each validation, the object ID is NOT present, so hasn't saved to DB yet
validating Charge - a child 1 chg a
validating Charge - a child 1 chg b
validating Charge - a child 1 chg a ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 1 chg b ** repeat
validating AChild - a child 1
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 1
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 2
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 1 ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 2 ** repeat
validating AChild - a child 2

validating Charge - a child 1 chg a ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 1 chg b ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 1 chg a ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 1 chg b ** repeat
validating AChild - a child 1       ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 1 ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 2 ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 1 ** repeat
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 2 ** repeat
validating AChild - a child 2       ** repeat

validating Charge - b child chg
validating Charge - b child chg     ** repeat
validating BChild - b child

validating Charge - b child chg     ** repeat
validating Charge - b child chg     ** repeat
validating BChild - b child         ** repeat

validating Charge - order chg
validating Charge - order chg       ** repeat
validating Order - order

<then a bunch of insert happens into the database, but somehow afterwards validations repeat again??? these last round of validations are basically what I would expect as I wrote initially above>

# Note in these validations, each object's ID is defined (as in it's saved to DB)
validating Charge - a child 1 chg a
validating Charge - a child 1 chg b
validating AChild - a child 1
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 1
validating Charge - a child 2 chg 2
validating AChild - a child 2
validating Charge - b child chg
validating BChild - b child
validating Charge - order chg
validating Order - order
```

What's causing the validation repetition, and how do I streamline this?

Comment: You have tied into the validation with a puts statement.  You have also called to validate children and charges from their associated parent objects.  Each time that the parent calls .valid? on a child your puts statement fires, then your puts statement fires again when the child actually saves. Because Active Record doesn't want to allow you to save anything that isn't valid it calls .valid? before saving the child as well.

Comment: So you're saying this is perfectly normal behavior?

Comment: Yes but I think you normally woudn't notice because there are no logs tied to validations.

Comment: Ok damn... so the reason I asked is because I'm really trying to use the `puts` to figure out an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253386/rails-in-what-order-do-model-callbacks-happen-for-nested-parent-child-models. Since that strategy doesn't work, do you have any insights on that question?

Comment: I think something messed up somewhere because in my case parent is validate first and then child.